# Unable to resolve path to module 'stream/promises'

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, import, eslint

For the following import in a typescript nodejs app

```
import { pipeline } from "stream/promises";
```

vscode / eslint is complaining `Unable to resolve path to module 'stream/promises'`

[image: sample]

This started occurring all of a sudden.

```
node -v v16.13.2
pnpm -v 6.29.1
"@types/node": "^17.0.12"
```

`stream/promises` is part of node. I've confirmed that the pipeline function and typescript type exist and work and the overall app still functions.

```
console.log({ pipeline }); // { pipeline: [Function: pipeline] }
```

Importing just `stream` works with no complaints. I've confirmed this error on a Windows 10 and Linux computer. Whats going on and how to resolve it without ignoring it?

Comment: Simply typing `import { pipeline }` I get auto-suggestion to `from 'stream'`. Probably that's how it should be imported, otherwise it might think 'stream/promises' is a file path?

Comment: @tromgy Thats for the sync version of `pipeline`. The async version is found under `stream/promises`

Comment: Did you solve it? same here..

Comment: @Danpe Nope. Had to eslint ignore.

Answer (score 5):

Need to make sure your node version is > v15. Note that if you're using nvm, your terminal node version could be different from the version vscode is using. You can see which version you have with nvm unload; node -v. You can consider adding nvm to your rc script files but sometimes it doesn't resolve fast enough and vs code complains.

Answer (score 0):

### For serverless / middyjs

> Error: "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'stream/promises'"

**Context:**

On debugging it is observed that the error is from `@middy/core` ( version: `4.6.5` ) which is dependent on `node:stream/promises` ([reference](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/blob/main/packages/core/index.js)) which requires node version `>=15.x`

### Fix here

Check for `serverless.yml` > `provider` > `runtime`

and update it to a version >= `15.x`

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
```

If you are using custom plugins like esbuild, make sure to update to the same node version

```yaml
custom:
    esbuild:
      bundle: true
      target: node16
      platform: node
```

---

> Note: If you are not using `stream/promises` in your code and still facing the error ( like I did ), check for any recent package updates in the code and see if they internally use `stream/promises`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `"@types/node"` in your `package.json`. and make sure its version is > 15, e.g.

```
"@types/node": "^18.11.0",
```